# Show a scroll menu if there are more than X rows

Tags: jquery

I made this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/2PeEK/

this show a menu when the user presses the image, and close the menu if the user presses it again.

I am trying to do the next thing:

if the number of the `<li>` is less than 7, show only the number of rows (for 4 `<li>` show a menu of 4 rows. for 2, show 2). but if there are 7 `<li>` or more, show a scroll.

any help appreciated!

Comment: Which bit are you stuck on - counting the elements or displaying the scroll bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to dynamically calculate it without setting hard values in CSS

```
var m = $('.menu'), //cache for performance
mh = m.height(), //get actual height
lih = mh / $('.menu li').length, //calculate the height of one of the LI's
max = 7, //what's the max amount of rows we want to show
mth = lih *max; //the height the container should be set to
```

Then just make a conditional

```
if(mh > (lih * max)){ //if the menu height is greater than 7 li's
    m.css({'maxHeight' : mth, 'overflow-y': 'scroll'});
}else{ //it's not greater
    m.css({'maxHeight': 'none', 'overflow-y' : 'auto'}); 
}
```

[Here's the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XKMpQ/)

Answer (score 4):

Adding

```
  max-height: 240px;
  overflow-y: auto;
```

to your `.menu` css gets the required result without JS, if that's good enough? Simpler and faster.

Comment: i think you need to update height to be 252px which equal to 7*36

Answer (score 1):

I would do based on em's rather than a fixed pixel height so the height is based on the size of the list text:

```
.menu {
    max-height: 15.75em;
    overflow-y: auto;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1.25em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3DWKP/1/

You have .5em of padding top and bottom on the a tags, so so line-height 1.25em + 1em of padding = 2.25em per list item. for 7 list items as a maximum height, that would be 7 * 2.25 = 15.75 ems for max-height.

Answer (score 1):

Using simple math equations you need to stop the height into (7*36) where 7 equal to number of `li` you want to show and 36 equal to the height of individual `li` so simple add to your `.menu` class the following rules

```
.menu{
    max-height: 240px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    //the rest of yout css rules
}
```